# How do I resolve ExecuteError: table is invalid in below script?

Tags: python, runtime-error, arcpy

When running the following script, this error appears:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "E:\Python_scripts\Indices_to_platform_indicesgdb_V01.py", line 41, in 
>       arcpy.CopyRaster_management(latest_raster,out_loc + "/" + latest_raster,"DEFAULTS","","","","","")
>     File "F:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 12737, in CopyRaster
>       raise e
>   ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
>   The table name is invalid.
>   No spatial reference exists.
>   The table was not found. [aqi_19_q4_i.tif]
>   Failed to execute (CopyRaster).

Code is as follows:

```
# Import system modules
import arcpy
import os

# Check out the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension license
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

from arcpy.sa import *


#Set input and output locations
in_loc = "S://gisdata/maintained/software_versions"
print in_loc
out_loc = "S://gisdata/maintained/current/Platform_indices_test.gdb"
print out_loc

#Set workspace location
arcpy.env.workspace = in_loc

index_list =['aqi', 'css']
#define latest_edition
latest_edition = 0

for ind in index_list:
  search_string = ind + "*_i.tif"
  print search_string
  raster_list = arcpy.ListRasters(search_string,"ALL")

  for i, obj in enumerate(raster_list):
    edition = int(obj[4:6] + obj[8:9])
    if edition > latest_edition:
      latest_edition = edition
      print latest_edition
      latest_raster = obj
  arcpy.CopyRaster_management(latest_raster,out_loc + "/" + latest_raster,"DEFAULTS","","","","","")


enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

`.tif` cannot be saved in a file geodatabase (`.gdb`). Also, a raster cannot have a dot in its name when saving to a `gdb`. You should either save the output in a folder or remove the extension `.tif` from the name.